# Windows Forms with embeddeed XNA - key press

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, key

I'm making a game with XNA embedded in Win Forms (i use win froms for menu, and render xna window in picture box)
The problem appears at keys detection. I don't know why, but ENTER key is detected in forms only when i press ALT in the same time.  ;(
the same with other keys such as SHIFT.
The next problem appears when SPACE is pressed, i don't try to handle it , ut always when it's pressed the window start to blink very fast .

Any ideas why?

Comment: Problem is now solved, I noticed that had many panels, and it wasn't clear which one receives press button event, Setting demanded panel to Active solved my problem.